# Getting a Syntax error for the variable after Having Count in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the code I was given by my professor:

```
SELECT fName, lName, NoOfMovies
FROM Directors D, (
SELECT dID, COUNT(*) NoOfMovies
FROM MovieDirectors
GROUP BY dID
HAVING COUNT(*) > =500) AS T
WHERE D.dID = T.dID
ORDER BY NoOfMovies;
```

The error code for sql is "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2."
We are actually just supposed to be learning indexes. Her code is supposed to be correct, yet when I let her know that she has an error, she will not help. I have attempted to rewrite the code:

```
Select fName, lName, NoOfMovies 
From Directors D Join moviedirectors MD on (D.dID=MD.dID)
GROUP by D.dID 
Having COUNT(*) >=500 As T
Where D.dID =MD.dID
ORDER by NoOfMovies;
```

Yet, I am still getting an error that I am not using the correct syntax near the variable T.My error code is: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'As T
 Where D.dID =MD.dID
 ORDER by NoOfMovies LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4." I am running this in phpmyadmin. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the error you're seeing for the top code snippet (your professor's)? Your second snippet is incorrect as you cannot alias a `HAVING` expression

Comment: I don't see the work LIMIT anywhere in your query.

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. Per Eric's comment, the given code cannot cause that error. Also read [ask]. Once you have run your MCVE, edit it into your question and also edit in all the solutions you ruled out from googling any error message(s) & many clear, concise, specific phrasings of your question/problem/goal (without your particular names & line numbers). Use one googling as title/tags. PS Clearly the `> =500` is wrong. But--is that what you were actually given?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The code should probably look like this:

```
select d.fName, d.lName, COUNT(*) as NoOfMovies 
from Directors d join
     moviedirectors md
     on d.dID = md.dID
group by d.fName, d.lName
having count(*) >= 500
order by NoOfMovies;
```

Notes:

- Qualify all the column names with the name of the table they are coming from.
- Always use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.
- A `WHERE` clause would go right after the `FROM`, but the clause is not necessary.
- The columns in the `GROUP BY` should match the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Upvoted, and probably the exact answer the OP wants, but if there be a chance of two directors having the same name the `ID` could be used to distinguish.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Amusingly, that is true in the IMDB database.  It is rather hard to find the duplicated directors, though.

Comment: Since the given instructor code cannot cause that error & needn't be wrong, what is the point of your answer? You should ask for clarification, downvote & close vote, not answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your rewrite is actually very close, but I would use this slight modification:

```
SELECT
    d.ID,
    d.fName,
    d.lName,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfMovies 
FROM Directors d
INNER JOIN moviedirectors md
    ON d.dID = md.dID
GROUP BY
    d.dID, d.fName, d.lName
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 500;
ORDER BY
    NoOfMovies;
```

The only major change here is the removal of the `WHERE` clause, which no longer serves a purpose.  It is no longer needed because that logic has become part of the `ON` clause.  I also group the first and last name, in addition to the ID.  If the ID uniquely determines the first and last name this may not be necessary, but I did it just to be safe.

Comment: You have a column in your `GROUP BY` that isn't in the `SELECT`

Comment: @Phil But is that a problem for MySQL?  Let me update.

Comment: eh, probably not. MySQL is too forgiving IMO :)

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen. It actually worked. I had edited my code before. I had only put the alias in the having count because she had. I get what you did and it has helped me so much. Thank you!

Comment: Since the given instructor code cannot cause that error & needn't be wrong, what is the point of your answer? You should ask for clarification, downvote & close vote, not answer.

Comment: @Ashley Your instructor didn't "put the alias in the having count", they put it in the first/outer `from` after the subselect being aliased. You need to read an intro to `select` expressions. This answer doesn't explain what is (allegedly) wrong with your instructor's code.

Comment: I think it’s probably safe to assume that there’s a functional dependency here. All the same, no harm in grouping on all the unaggregated columns.

Comment: @philipxy I directly copied my instructor' s code. It Was the alias in the having Count that was causing it.

Comment: @Ashley I repeat, your professor's code has no "alias in the having Count". So it's still not clear what you think is wrong with it. Please explain what you think is wrong it using different & more words. *Your* code has an illegal `as`/alias in the `having`. It also has a `where` where not allowed. Also yours with the obvious fixes, and these 2 answers, even ignoring their extra returned columns, depending on code you have not given, *do not always return the same results as it does*. Please address all my comments.